# Getting only digits out of a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this string - "4,450.50 $".

I need just the numbers from this string. So in this example i would like to get the number - 4450.50 back.

How could I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = "4,450.50 $"
Float str.scan(/[\d.]/).join
# => 4450.5
```